# Shell Scripting to add content to a file

Tags: shell

I have a bunch of files which need to be run on different platforms with a slightly different code. I have to add some code to some of my code files. I know how to find the files using shell scripting. I use this command:

```
find . -type f | grep \*.C
```

After I find the file, I need to find a text line and then add some code before that text line and after that text line. Then I want to save the file. Is there a way to do this using shell scripting. I know about the sed command, but that's only used when I want to replace text. I need to add new code somewhere in the file as explained.

Thank you.

Comment: Yes. There is always a way to do that. But suggesting a good/right/better/best/not-bad way to do that requires considerably more detail, including sample text, and preferably, examples of what you've already tried...

Comment: What issue are you running into using sed?  You're replacing text you found with itself and two other lines right?

Comment: sed 's/^your_line$/new_line_before&new_line_after/g'

Comment: Actually the reason I didn't write the code is because I wanted to try the commands by myself. I just want to know some commands. If you could give me a direction. Like a command to find text in a file and then a command to write to the file at the desired location, before and after the text was found. I would really appreciate it. If you still have problems understanding the question, please let me know and I will write some script to show you. Pardon me if I wasted your time.

Comment: miah: No I am not replacing text. I find a text string in a file and I add some code before that line. I don't need to replace anything. I need to add some code before a line.

Comment: I don't believe there is any command to "insert" text into a file. Think about it: after inserting your text the program would need to rewrite the rest of the file anyway to shift it. sed does exactly what you want.

Comment: can you give me an example of inserting text? And also, do you mean that its better to make a new file with the inserted text?

Comment: If you want more control, for a more complicated example, you might want to learn Perl. But this example (inserting a line before and/or after a line matching a regex) is doable with sed.

Comment: @ctn `sed` is absolutely able to insert text into a file - see the `a` and `i` commands. It is true that the rest of the stream then gets shifted down, but that's one of the reasons `sed` is called `sed` - it's a `S`tream `ED`itor.

Comment: @twalberg yes, you're right... I was thinking of a command that can insert at a fixed offset.

Comment: @user2438113 see ctn's first comment, if that's not what you want, we need a more accurate description and an example.

Comment: @user2438113 It's a good idea to create a separate file in order to make sure your script works properly (at least at first). But you can use "sed -i" to change in place.

Comment: okay, that makes sense. I am new so didn't know that much about sed. So what should I do? Create a new file? Or is there a way I can add the text and not shift the stream? Like a pointer to my new code?

Comment: @user2438113 I'm sorry, I confused you with the shifting part... virtually all programs that manipulate text files need to shift it if they want to change something inside that results in a new file size (like adding/deleting text). That's normal and not easily avoidable. It's only avoidable if you replace a text with another one of the exact same size and I can only think of a solution in C.

Comment: okay, so I checked and there and 50 files which need to be changed and creating a new file for each won't be an option then I guess.

Comment: okay, I guess I will give your suggestion a shot. I was just worried if I change those files, maybe their run-time processing would get affected.

Comment: Thank you ctn. You seem like a genius in this stuff :)

Comment: np... good luck with your script.

Comment: I have another question... :

Comment: So this command doesn't work:
find . -type f -print0 | grep \.txt$ | xargs -0 -n 1
but this one does:
find . -type f | grep \.txt$ | xargs -n 1

Comment: @user2438113 Just to be sure, that should be `xargs -<zero> -n 1`, not `xargs -<capital-O> -n 1`.

Comment: it is a -0 not a capital o